# How to make sprites spawn at random?

Tags: python, pygame

I am fairly new at pygame so I need some help with a few problems. I'm doing a snake game but with enemies and a "maze".

My biggest problem is, I think, rather glaring if you run my code. I have coded the 'food' to appear at random but instead of appearing at 1 random place, it is moving around the screen. [SOLVED]

My second problem is that I want to spawn several enemies (around 5) at random locations instead of just one enemy but I don't know how to.

My third problem is bullet to wall collision detection. It works if I shoot the bullets one at a time but if I shoot multiple bullets at once, all the bullets will pass through the wall except the last one which will hit the wall.

These are the enemy codes:

```
Code is removed for now. Will re-upload in 1 to 2 months.
```

```
enemy = Enemy(500, 500, 1, wall_list)
all_sprite_list.add(enemy)
```

These are the codes for the bullets:

```
Code is removed for now. Will re-upload in 1 to 2 months.
```

```
Code is removed for now. Will re-upload in 1 to 2 months.
```

and this is my entire code if it helps:

```
Code is removed for now. Will re-upload in 1 to 2 months.
```

I appreciate any help I can get, even if its not related to the questions that I asked above. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an instance to the Enemy class and spawn it to add another enemy, just give it some different coordinates then the first one.:

```
enemy = Enemy(500, 500, 1, wall_list)
enemy2 = Enemy(400,400,1, wall_list)
all_sprite_list.add(enemy)
all_sprite_list.add(enemy2)
```

For the food, id add another class like you did before.

```
class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10,10])
        self.image.fill(green)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(20,780)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(20,780)
```

remove the following line:

```
pygame.draw.rect(win,green,[randfoodx,randfoody,10,10])
```

add this in the same location as where you spawn the enemies and the player sprites:

```
food = Food()
all_sprite_list.add(food)
```

For the bullet problem you mentioned, change the following line:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(bullet, wall_list):
```

into:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, wall_list):
```

This is important since when you spawn a new bullet, the bullet variable name will be overwritten.

all together:

```
#Import

import pygame
import math
import time
import random
from pygame.locals import *

#Initialize

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Essential Python CA1")

#Define

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 250, 250)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (70,130,180)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 60)
display_instructions = True
instruction_page = 1

#Bullet

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([5, 5])
        self.image.fill(green)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.vec.x, self.vec.y)

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, wall_list):
            self.kill()


#Enemy

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, speed, walls):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(red)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        self.speed = speed # speed of the enemy
        self.walls = walls # walls for the collision test

    def move(self, player):
        dx, dy = player.rect.x - self.rect.x, player.rect.y - self.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        Enemy.move_x = dx * self.speed
        Enemy.move_y = dy * self.speed

    def update(self):

        self.rect.x += round(self.move_x)
        block_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_collide:
            if self.move_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += round(self.move_y)
        block_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_collide:
            if self.move_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom



#Player

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    move_x = 0
    move_y = 0
    walls = None

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(white)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.move_x += x
        self.move_y += y

    def update(self):

        self.rect.x += self.move_x

        block_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_collide:
            if self.move_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.move_y

        block_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_collide:

            if self.move_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

#Maze
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(blue)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.width = 10
        self.height = 10

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10,10])
        self.image.fill(green)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(20,780)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(20,780)


all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

walls = ((0, 0, 10, 800),
         (40, 40, 10, 75),
         (50, 40, 190, 10),
         (790, 10, 10, 800),
         (10, 0, 800, 10),
         (10, 790, 800, 10),
         (50, 750, 170, 10),
         (40, 145, 10, 615),
         (80, 710, 310, 10),
         (250, 750, 110, 10),
         (390, 680, 10, 80),
         (400, 750, 200, 10),
         (430, 710, 10, 50),
         (470, 710, 200, 10),
         (630, 750, 130, 10),
         (750, 40, 10, 720),
         (550, 40, 210, 10),
         (270, 40, 250, 10),
         (410, 80, 310, 10),
         (410, 120, 310, 10),
         (80, 80, 300, 10),
         (370, 40, 10, 90),
         (130, 120, 240, 10),
         (300, 160, 450, 10),
         (50, 160, 220, 10),
         (700, 710, 50, 10),
         (80, 670, 670, 10),
         (80, 160, 10, 510),
         (80, 200, 100, 10),
         (210, 200, 120, 10),
         (270, 200, 10, 90),
         (120, 240, 150, 10),
         (80, 280, 250, 10),
         (360, 200, 100, 10),
         (310, 240, 150, 10),
         (460, 160, 10, 130),
         (360, 280, 100, 10))

for wall_coords in walls:
    wall = Wall(*wall_coords)
    wall_list.add(wall)
    all_sprite_list.add(wall)

player = Player(10, 10)
player.walls = wall_list
enemy = Enemy(500, 500, 1, wall_list)
enemy2 = Enemy(400,400,1, wall_list)
all_sprite_list.add(enemy)
all_sprite_list.add(enemy2)

food = Food()
all_sprite_list.add(food)

all_sprite_list.add(player)

#Start screen Loop
done = False
while not done and display_instructions:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            instruction_page += 1
            if instruction_page == 2:
                display_instructions = False

    # Set the screen background
    win.fill(black)

    if instruction_page == 1:

        text = font.render("Instructions:", True, white)
        win.blit(text, [10, 20])

        text = font.render("Use WASD, or the Arrow Keys to move", True, white)
        win.blit(text, [10, 100])

        text = font.render("Left click to shoot", True, white)
        win.blit(text, [10, 150])

        text = font.render("Can you beat your highscore?", True, red)
        win.blit(text, [100, 370])

        text = font.render("Click to start", True, white)
        win.blit(text, [270, 600])

    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()

# Programme loop
run = True

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            run = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.move(-2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.move(2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                player.move(0, -2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                player.move(0, 2)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.move(2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.move(-2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                player.move(0, 2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                player.move(0, -2)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            aim_pos = event.pos
            player_position = player.rect.center
            bullet_vec = pygame.math.Vector2(aim_pos[0] - player_position[0], aim_pos[1] - player_position[1]).normalize() * 10
            bullet = Bullet()
            bullet.rect.center = player.rect.center
            bullet.vec = bullet_vec
            all_sprite_list.add(bullet)

    enemy.move(player)
    all_sprite_list.update()

    win.fill(black)


    all_sprite_list.draw(win)

    # pygame.draw.rect(win,green,[randfoodx,randfoody,10,10])

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the food issue, you'd need it to only generate a piece of food if there are none on the map. Or if there were less than x. So set a numberOfFood variable, and instead of `while run:` you could put `while numberOfFood < 2:`